# GLSL - Passing coordinates to fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I have the following shaders

VertexShader

```
#version 330
layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 inColour;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 inTex;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 inNorm;
uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
out vec4 ShadowCoord;
void main()
{
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * transformationMatrix * vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
  ShadowCoord = gl_Position;
}
```

FragmentShader

```
#version 330
in vec4 ShadowCoord;
out vec4 FragColor;
uniform sampler2D heightmapTexture;
void main()
{
  FragColor =  vec4(vec3(clamp(ShadowCoord.x/500,0.0,1.0),clamp(gl_FragCoord.y/500,0.0,1.0),0.0),1.0);
}
```

What I would expect this to do is to draw the scene, with green in the top left, yellow in the top right, red in the bottom right and black in the bottom left.  Indeed this is what happens when I replace `ShadowCoord.x` with `gl_FragCoord.x` in my fragment shader.  Why then, do I only get a vertical gradient of green?  Evidently something screwy is happening to my ShadowCoord.  Anyone know what it is?

Comment: "*Anyone know what it is?*" No. Because the contents of `ShadowCoord` depend *entirely* on the contents of two matrices that we have no idea what they are. We don't even know if you're using a perspective or orthographic project.

Comment: Ok, but the point is that if I replace ShadowCoord with gl_FragCoord in the frag shader then it works.  Is gl_FragCoord not derived from gl_Position?  If so why does ShadowCoord not undergo the same interpolation? <EDIT> FYI, its a perspective projection of a camera transformation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, `gl_FragCoord` is "derived from `gl_Position`". That does *not* mean that it is *equal to* it.

`gl_Position` is the clip-space position of a particular vertex. `gl_FragCoord.xyz` contains the window-space position of the fragment. These are not the same spaces. To get from one to the other, the graphics hardware performs [a number of transformations](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing).

Transformations that *do not* happen to other values. That's why the fragment shader doesn't call it `gl_Position`; because it's not that value anymore. It's a new value computed from the original based on various state (the viewport & depth range) that the user has set.

User-defined vertex parameters are interpolated as they are. Nothing "screwy" is happening with your user-defined interpolated parameter. The system is doing exactly what it should: interpolating the value you passed across the triangle's surface.

Comment: Right that makes sense.  How would one tell the system to do those processes on a different variable then?  Say, eventually, ShadowCoord is given by some other transformation matrix, and I want to then get the coordinates of its 'fragment'.  Would I have to manually implement what is described in the link?

Comment: "*How would one tell the system to do those processes on a different variable then?*" You don't; you'll have to compute it yourself. It's just another matrix multiply; you can just fold it into the back end of the matrix you're already using.